# How to keep login status in meteor offline groundDB

Tags: meteor, authentication, offline

I know groundDB is used for offline Meteor.

What I want to know is how to save login status or login user info to GroundDB or localStorage so that the app keeps the login status even terminate app and restart it in offline status.

I've googled for this problem, but couldn't find solution.

Please help me!